# Getting duplicate icons when running my app

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I had a previous Android project I was working on it but suddenly an error occured in that project and I had no solution except to create a new project on visual studio and copy all my files, activities, libs to my new project and I did. First time I have run my new Android project, the app worked well as the old project did except I am having two app icons on my home screen, so I reviewed my MainActivity and other activities to check if by mistake I have precised my app icon twice but it wasn't the case.

`Android Manifest` (full file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 package="com.Dabboussi.AAD" android:installLocation="auto" 
 android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" 
        android:largeHeap="true" 
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" 
        android:label="AAD" 
        android:icon="@drawable/Icon"> 
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's a screenshot of the duplicate icons[image]
I don't have any idea why this is happening. I checked the `MainLauncher` and Activities Label, they are all good. So what is causing this issue ?

Comment: please add your manifest completely or at least add your launcher activity section

Comment: Pls post the full manifest. And describe more clear, I don't understand what duplicated icons is. A screenshot may help

Comment: That's my full manifest.

Comment: @TamHuynh I have edited my question and provided a screenshot please check

Comment: That's weird. Do both icons have the same behavior (launch the same activity)?May be you recently change the app's package name, it will create a new instance of the app

Comment: @Tam Huynh  One of them is working fine, the other one crashes when I open it. Yes I did changed the app's package name in order to solve the issue but it didn't. If the package name is causing a new instance of the app, it should do that only once, what do I need to do ? Do I rechange the app's package to it's old name ?

Comment: Just uninstall both of the app and rebuild it

Comment: @Tam Huynh I have tried, didn't worked. But I noticed, when I uninstalled the first one, the second got unstalled automatically.

Comment: There may have some problem during android studio auto refactoring when you change the package name. Recheck all the package name string in the app to make sure they are all the same. Or try a finest dummy solution: create another project and copy-paste all the code to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out that when I was copying the references from my old project to the new one, I have mistaken and copied the `.dll` of the old project. So I removed it and it's fine now.